# Object Pools in Cocos2D-X v3.0 Final - Deprecated CCArray

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

In the search for true randomness using cocos2d-X, without the need of excessive conditionals; the algorithm of interest utilizes 2 CCArray(s) to allocate and combine functions on two different object pools.

We Create a 'pool' for an object 'leather' and 'leatherSelection'. We Overwrite CCSprite with a custom class named 'SaddleManifold'

/**

On the header, using deprecated Cocos2D-x define an array of 'leather' types.

```
CCArray * _leather;
CCArray * _leatherSelection;
```

The use of CCArray is obviously unfit for the new cocos2D-x library. I am looking for ways to re-write my code using the new cocos2D-X V3 library which introduces vectors.

```
/** Destroyer **/
SaddleManifold::~SaddleManifold() { }

/**implementation class **/

_leather = CCArray::createWithCapacity(5);
_leather->retain();

 //Attempt to overload

_leatherSelection = CCArray::createWithCapacity(4);
_leatherSelection->retain();

  /** I get thrown an 'out-of-line' definition when building this signature **/
  void SaddleManifold::initSaddleManifold(Saddle * saddle) {

    .....}
```

Now if I try this:

```
/* Saddle is a Sprite! */

  Saddle * saddle;

  /*set boundaries*/
    while (currentSaddletWidth < _minSaddleManifoldWidth) {
```

For example: The saddle chooses randomly from an array of leather types; width parameters are embedded. Here's an excerpt of the code in question:

```
   saddle = (Saddle *) _leatherArray->objectAtIndex(_leatherArrayIndex);
    _leatherArrayIndex+;

    /**this does not run since it relies on that deprecated count()**/

    if (_leatherArrayIndex == _leatherArray> count()) {
        _leatherArrayIndex =0;
    }

    this->initSaddleManifold(saddle);

  /** width assignment differential **/
    currentSaddleWidth += saddle->getWidth();

    _leatherSelection->addObject(obstacle);
```

Which would be the best way to transition from CCArray to the new alternative? Is run-time any different than using CCArray?

Comment: Do you want a way to pick a random object from your pool using a new class Vector of cocos2d-x 3.0?

Comment: I can't seem to move forward because count() is declared differently ....CLASSIC: unsigned int CCArray::count()
{
    return data->num;
}
and I can't assemble the implementation since it's no longer available in its classic form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocos2d-x comes with a new Vector class that replaces the now deprecated CCArray. Major differences (in relation with your code) are:

1) Vector is used as a static object. You don't need to declare a pointer to it :

```
class SpritesPool { 
   ....
   protected:
       cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Sprite*> _leather;
       cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Sprite*> _leatherSelection;
};

SpritesPool::SpritesPool() : _leather(5), _leatherSelection(4) {}
```

2) Vector is similar (and based on) a normal std::vector then you have all the well known vector functions:

```
saddle = (Saddle *) _leatherArray.at(_leatherArrayIndex); 
....
if (_leatherArrayIndex == _leatherArray.size()) {
    _leatherArrayIndex =0;
}
...
_leatherSelection.pushBack(obstacle);
```

You have also a method for pick a random object from the vector

```
saddle = (Saddle *) _leatherArray.getRandomObject();
```

that maybe can help you with your implementation.

Comment: Excellent Response, Thank you! Indeed, Cocos2D-X V3 replaces __Array with C++ Templates; For example, 'pushBack' inspired by the original 'push_back' from the stl used for lists. Brilliant!

In case y'all wanted more info: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 0):

You can use __Array instead of CCArray.

```
__Array * _leather;
__Array * _leatherSelection;

_leatherSelection = CCArray::createWithCapacity(4);
_leatherSelection->retain();

_leather->addObject(new Ref);
_leather->insertObject(<#cocos2d::Ref *object#>, <#ssize_t index#>);
_leather->getObjectAtIndex(<#ssize_t index#>);
_leather->getIndexOfObject(<#cocos2d::Ref *object#>);
_leather->getLastObject();
```