# Alternative for object pools in cocos2d-x v3.3

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

i am migrating my game from AndEngine, there I always used object pools for efficient use of objects like bullets etc in my game. What alternate do i have in cocos2d-x for this scenario?

Comment: Write a custom object pool, I don't think there's one built into cocos2d-x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Cocos2d-x doesn't have built-in object pool. Cocos2d-JS(Cocos2d-HTML5) does have it in extensions.

- http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/v3/cc-pool/en
- https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-html5/blob/develop/extensions/ccpool/CCPool.js

But you can implement your own object pool like the example of some Cocos2d-x book.

- https://github.com/setiawand/SkyDefenseExample/blob/master/Classes/HelloWorldScene.h
- https://github.com/setiawand/SkyDefenseExample/blob/master/Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp
- [Object Pools in Cocos2D-X v3.0 Final - Deprecated CCArray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23646731/629118) for migration 2.x to 3.x

  void createPools(void);